# innodb_buffer_pool_size not changing

Tags: configuration, mysql

I have encountered a weird problem with innodb_buffer_pool_size configuration on 5.5.23-1~dotdeb.0 (Debian):

Whatever new value that I choose in my.cnf for innodb_buffer_pool_size (e.g 3G, 4G, 8000M), after restarting mysql I still get innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128 M.

Values of other my.cnf parameters can be changed without any issue.

I have also checked and have no other my.cnf on the file system other than /etc/mysql/my.dnf. So does this mean that  innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128 M is hard-coded at compile time? If so, how can I fix this? If not, what can possibly have caused the problem? Thanks

P.S. I first [asked](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17075/innodb-buffer-pool-size-not-changed) this question at dba forum but people there seem not to have insight about mysql debian package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to put the config WITHIN [mysqld] block in my.cnf to take effect.

more details [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/17151/2953)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have space between the number '128' and 'M'?? Atleast in my mysql installation the space is forbidden between them, altough I checked this only on 5.1.x version.

Comment: Good point, but there is no spcae in my.cnf. Here I just copied the output of TunningPrimer script.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was `innodb_buffer_pool_instances`.

Since I was reducing `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, it became less than one 1GB per instance, so it ended up rounding it.

When I also reduced the *instances*, it finally changed the *pool size*!